# Triggers Sentencia INSERTED | Duda

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Hola compañeros tengo una duda.
Tengo este Trigger

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda es sobre ese inserted. Como funciona realmente?... Tengo entendido que hace referencia a una tabla , en este caso creo que seria la tabla pedido. Pero cuando cambio el inserted por el nombre de la tabla 'pedido' me sale error al modificar los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando intento modificar me sale esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Porque funciona con el inserted y con el nombre de la tabla no? no debería de ser igual ?

Answer (score 1):

Inserted es una `pseudo-tabla`, que básicamente significa que tiene las filas nuevas o modificadas de la tabla a la que pertenece el trigger.

En tú caso, Inserted tiene la misma estructura que la tabla pedido, pero su contenido es la fila que se está actualizando en ese momento.

Por ejemplo si actualizas la fila de `id = 1`, con esta sentencia:

```
Update pedido 
  Set Descripcion = 'Zumo', 
      Precio = 8 
  Where id_pedido=1;
```

- Inserted.Id_pedido = 1
- Inserted.id_venta  = 1
- Inserted.descripcion = 'Zumo'
- Inserted.precio = 8

Porque estás en el trigger de Update para la tabla de Pedido.

La diferencia está en que inserted no tiene todas las filas de la tabla pedido, solo tiene aquellas que se han modificado, en la sentencia que se está finalizando.

Pero este trigger además contiene la pseudo-tabla `deleted`, que para la misma sentencia:

- Deleted.Id_pedido = 1
- Deleted.id_venta  = 1
- Deleted.descripcion = 'Sangría'
- Deleted.precio = 25

O lo que es lo mismo, los valores que tenían las columnas de la fila que se está modificando, antes de esta sentencia.

Ahora bien hay dos errores en el trigger. Uno el que muestras, y otro que funciona pero no bien.

El que muestras, te dice que la subquery está retornando más de un valor a un contenedor, en el que solo puede coger un valor escalar.

```
Declare @id Int = (Select id_Venta from pedido)
```

- @id= **un solo valor** de tipo int
- Select id_Venta from pedido=

  - 1
  - 1
  - 1
  - 2
  - 2
  - 2

Tres unos correspondientes a las filas de id_pedido 1, 2 y 3 y tres doses correspondientes a las filas de id_pedido 4,5,6.

Por tanto una variable puede recibir un valor y no los valores de varias filas. Pero es que además, no tienes referencia a que fila se está actualizando, y por eso es necesario que entre en juego inserted.

**Problema de conjuntos**

El segundo error que tienes, y que funciona pero no siempre, es que has definido el trigger como si la sentencia fuera escalar. Que solo puedas modificar una fila de cada vez con una update. Si vas añadiendo pedidos, y diferentes ventas y actualizas varias a la vez.

```
Update pedido 
   set precio = 14 
  Where descripcion = 'Sangria';
```

Aquí tienes un problema. El trigger solo está identificando Un `id_venta` cuando podría haber varios. Y solo actualizaría un registro de la tabla `venta`.

Por esto los triggers se tienen que plantear siempre como conjuntos. Son las filas en plural de la tabla a la que hacen referencia, y no la fila.

[Triggers After Update. ¿Cómo funcionan?](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/15/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-after-for-update/)